# Couldn't find rabbitmq after installing the package using pip

Tags: python, pip, rabbitmq

I want to install rabbitMQ on my linux box. I installed the package with the command

```
pip install rabbitmq
```

and the package is installed successfully.

```
pip freeze
rabbitmq==0.2.0
```

However, when I try to run `rabbitmq-server` I get the following errors:

````
/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server: line 28: cd: /var/lib/rabbitmq: No such file or directory
id: rabbitmq: no such user
/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server: line 32: [: too many arguments
id: rabbitmq: no such user
/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server: line 34: [: too many arguments
su: user rabbitmq does not exist```
````

There are two issues:
Firstly:
I checked `var/lib/` and couldn't find rabbitmq directory there. 
Is there a reason why pip didn't install that for me ?
Second: I couldn't figure out what `su: user rabbitmq does not exist` is pointing at exactly. Any advise on how to fix these issues ?

Comment: `pip install rabbitmq` will install the `rabbitmq` library for python, not the binaries/libraries needed to run a rabbitmq service on your linux machine. You probably need to `apk/apt/yum/etc install rabbitmq` instead using your distribution's package manager

Comment: Check https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html for how to download and install RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1):

the Python package rabbitmq is not rabbitmq itself, but a Python binding to it.  It looks like the underlying installation is not complete - you normally wouldn't get that from pip, but from your distribution's package management system. That installation will normally set up the user the server will run under as well.